# No puedo desplegar una aplicacion eh heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

En local me funciona bien, pero al intentar subir a heroku me aparece el siguiente error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/portalm80ve.git'
```

Este es el error log desde donde aparecen los errores:...

```
    Bundle complete! 23 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (48.60s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.2, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!
 !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- sprockets/processed_asset
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets/sprockets_overrides/processed_asset.rb:1:in `<main>'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets-rails3.rb:10:in `block in <main>'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets-rails3.rb:9:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets-rails3.rb:9:in `<main>'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
 !     /tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
 !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
 !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
 !
/app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sprockets/processed_asset
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets/sprockets_overrides/processed_asset.rb:1:in `<main>'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets-rails3.rb:10:in `block in <main>'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets-rails3.rb:9:in `each'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.2.9/lib/turbo-sprockets-rails3.rb:9:in `<main>'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/tmp/build_10190cfff0a96f59e4b7329dafc201d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:811:in `rake'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:134:in `log'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:832:in `allow_git'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:103:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:92:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:134:in `log'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Agrega más detalles, ¿se muestra este error cuando haces que? que comandos realizas (ver [ask]), me parece que primeramente necesitas realizar un pull.

Comment: @J.Castro Revertí tu edición debido a que los _backtrace_ de errores se leen mucho más sencillo en formato código en que formato  _quote_.

Comment: Hola, intenta precompilar los assets antes de subir el código con lo siguiente

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Gracias a todos, la solución la encontre haciendo push en git a mi carpeta de assets específicamente, aparte de todo el repositorio